# iPhone app crash logs

Tags: iphone, crash, logging

Can we create and get application crash log from iPhone? If yes then, is the result which we will get will be useful?

Thanks,
Aashutosh

Answer (score 2):

If it's for your iPhone — Open Xcode, goto Window -> Organizer. From there, find your device. There should be a crash log tab.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your device to your mac and look for "Organizer" in the Xcode menu. There you should be able to access the crash logs. I did it just today but didn't find it too useful.. but see for yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good technical note about this: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html

Crash logs may reveal you a bit why you application crashed and what it was doing just before the crash. But it is much more easier to fix the bug if you can make the game crash in debug mode.