# iPhone program crash on float to string conversion

Tags: iphone, string, crash, floating-point

I have an issue in getting a string that has been converted from a float to display in a label in a custom cell in a UITableView.

The program will crash if I try to assign the value of the float to the label. If I leave "strAIAreaIncrease = @"6.5%";" uncommented, the program works fine - but without the calculated value.

```
strAIAreaIncrease = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",fltAreaIncrease];
strAIAreaIncrease = [strAIAreaIncrease stringByAppendingString:@"%"];
DebugLog(@"The value of float num is %.2f", fltAreaIncrease);
DebugLog(@"The value of the string is %@", strAIAreaIncrease);
// strAIAreaIncrease = @"6.5%";
```

The Debugger Console shows the following:

> ```
> 2010-11-14 19:52:38.122 Building Use[855:207]  The value of float num is 2.50
> 2010-11-14 19:52:38.123 Building Use[855:207]  The value of the string is 2.50%
> ```

I have used this format on other custom cell labels without issue. Anyone have any idea as to what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: There's not nearly [enough information](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). How do you assign a float to the label? How have you customized the cell? Does your code work with a standard table cell? What reason for the crash is given? What's the stack trace? (the last two can be found in the [crash logs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html), [accessible via the Organizer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275190/iphone-app-crash-logs)) What we really need is a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: "How do you assign a float to the label?" - That is the whole issue for me. I am trying to change the float to a string in order to get it to read-out in the label. This approach has worked with other cells in the same program, but with enough back and forth that program will crash. I think that this is due to the memory leak I have read about when constantly updating strings. I am still learning about the crash logs and will look deeper into your suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use NSMutableString instead:

e.g.

```
NSMutableString* straIAreaIncrease 
    = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", fltAreaIncreas];
[strAIAreaIncrease appendString:@"%%"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have not tried it yet, but I am learning about NSMutableString. If what I have read so far is true, then I may have a lot of NSStrings to switch to NSMutableStrings. This might also explain a few other anomalies I have experienced lately. It may be a few days before I can implement this, and I will report back the results.

Comment: @user484340 (you might want to [give yourself a meaningful name](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): since the app doesn't crash with `strAIAreaIncrease = @"6.5%"`, I very much doubt switching to `NSMutableString` will help, though I cannot say for certain without seeing a more complete code sample and the crash reason and stack trace. Whether to use `NSString` or `NSMutableString` depends on whether or not you need to be able to change the string contents. Which to use is often a matter of efficiency rather than correctness.

Comment: OK, I have a better name now. I am new to iPhone programming and am not a professional - I learned programming with Visual Basic. I am doing a lot of changing of values to the strings and arrays as well as doing a lot of conversions back and forth between integers and floats to strings. I have been looking for a way to track the cause of the crash and  you have given me a clue - seek out the stack trace, but I don't yet know how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have tried to implement NSMutabeString without success. It is obvious that I am missing a fundemental understanding of the MSMutableString.

I think that the way that I am creating it is part of the problem. I need to be able to pass the variable to several methods, so I am trying to create it in the header. It seems all of the examples I come across create the string within a method.

In my header I have:

```
NSMutableString *strAIAreaIncrease;
```

I think that this is a pert of the problem and I think that I need to assign it a value, but am not sure how. The Debugger Console gives the following:

```
2010-11-21 07:40:40.456 Building Use[1274:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSMutableString string:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2317c0'
```

Another question is this: If I am then using the MSMutableString value in an array, does the array have to be an MSMutable Array?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. As suggested by some of the respondents, the problem was not in the string. However, I learned a great deal about mutablestrings and I am going to migrate many of my strings to mutablestrings. The real problem is outlined in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246201/setting-final-string-values-of-arrays-in-voidviewwillappear-crash-vs-uitab

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the header. It seems that you are using

```
strAIAreaIncrease = [NSMutableString string:@"someString"];
```

But there is no method "string:" in the Class NSMutableString. Try to use

```
strAIAreaIncrease = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"someString"];
```

or

```
strAIAreaIncrease = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"someString %d", someInteger];
```

About your second question: No you don't have to use a NSMutableArray, when dealing with NSMutableString. The "Mutable" in NSMutableArray means that you can add and remove objects from the array after it is generated.